# First order differential equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

What method would you use to solve:

$$
(1+x^2)\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}=1+y^2 \;; \qquad  y(2)=3
$$

I am asking this because I only know two methods of solving the DEs - separation of variables and integrating factor. Since the separation of variables does not work here, I tried integrating factor, however, I don't know what to do with the $y^2$, because for the IF to work I need to get y on its own ($\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} + P(x)y = Q(x)$)

What method do I use to solve this?

Comment: I think that separation of variables works fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not separation? I get
$$
\frac{1}{1+y^2} \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} = \frac{1}{1+x^2}
$$

Comment: Oops, yes, something went wrong, lol